# PHP validation not working, overuled by form action

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to use my PHP form validation on quiz.php, but my code takes me straight to result.php without checking for empty fields..

Can someone tell me why the validation is not working? I'm not seeing any errors when pressing the submit button.

```
<?php

require_once("php/db.php");                 /* Database Class */
require_once('php/utils/is_email.php');     /* Email Validation Script */

if(isset($_POST['newcontact'])){
$contact = new Contact();
} else{

//header('Location: result.php');
}

/* Class Contact */
class Contact{

private $db;                        /* the database obj */

//we have to init $errors array, as otherwise form will produce errors on missing array entry
private $errors = array(            /* holds error messages */

'aanhef' => '',
'contactpersoon' => '',
'bedrijfsnaam' => '',
'email' => '',
'telefoon' => '',
'vraag1_antwoorden' => '',
'vraag2_antwoorden' => ''
);

private $num_errors;                /* number of errors in submitted form */

public function __construct(){

$this->db = new DB();
if(isset($_POST['newcontact']))
$this->processNewMessage();
}

public function processNewMessage(){

$aanhef         = $_POST['aanhef'];         
$contactpersoon     = $_POST['contactpersoon'];     
$bedrijfsnaam       = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
$telefoon       = $_POST['telefoon'];
$email          = $_POST['email'];
$vraag1_antwoorden  = $_POST['vraag1_antwoorden'];
$vraag2_antwoorden  = $_POST['vraag2_antwoorden'];

/* Server Side Data Validation */
if(!isset($aanhef)) {
$this->errors['aanhef'] = 'Vul uw aanhef in';
}
if(!isset($contactpersoon)) {
$this->errors['contactpersoon'] = 'Vul uw contactpersoon in';
}
if(!isset($bedrijfsnaam)) {
$this->errors['bedrijfsnaam'] = 'Vul uw bedrijfsnaam in';
}
if(!isset($telefoon)) {
$this->errors['telefoon'] = 'Vul uw telefoon in';
}
if(!isset($vraag1_antwoorden)) {
$this->errors['vraag1_antwoorden'] = 'Selecteer een antwoord a.u.b.';
}

if(!isset($vraag2_antwoorden)) {
$this->errors['vraag2_antwoorden'] = 'Selecteer een antwoord a.u.b.';
}
if(!isset($email)) {
$this->errors['email'] = 'Vul uw e-mail in';
}
/* No errors, insert in db

else*/
if($this->countErrors() == '') {
if(($ret = $this->db->dbNewMessage($aanhef, $contactpersoon, $bedrijfsnaam, $email, $telefoon, $vraag1_antwoorden, $vraag2_antwoorden)) > ''){
//$json = array('result'         => 1);
if(SEND_EMAIL)
$this->sendEmail($aanhef,$contactpersoon,$bedrijfsnaam,$email,$telefoon,$vraag1_antwoorden,$vraag2_antwoorden);
//This is for relocating to successful result page
header('Location: result.php');
} else {   

//This will need special treatment. You have to prepare an errorpage
//for database-related issues.

header("Location: database-error.html");
}
}
}

public function sendEmail($aanhef,$contactpersoon,$bedrijfsnaam,$email,$telefoon,$vraag1_antwoorden,$vraag2_antwoorden){
/* Just format the email text the way you want ... */
$message_body   = "<div style=\"font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;\">Hallo,<br><br>"
."Het volgende bedrijf heeft zich zojuist aangemeld voor de Veiligheids Quiz:</div><br>"
."<table cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" width=\"550px\"><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Bedrijfsnaam:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$bedrijfsnaam."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Aanhef:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$aanhef."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Contactpersoon:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$contactpersoon."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Telefoonnummer:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$telefoon."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">E-mail:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$email."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Antwoord vraag 1:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$vraag1_antwoorden."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Antwoord vraag 2:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$vraag2_antwoorden."</td></tr></table><br>";

// Geef GELDIGE adressen op
// Een korte benaming voor jouw website

$website_naam = 'Aanmelding Quiz';
// Jouw eigen geldige emailadres
$eigen_emailadres = 'MY MAIL';
// Een geldig emailadres voor errors
$error_emailadres = 'MY MAIL';
// De naam van de verzender
$naam_verzender = ''.$bedrijfsnaam.'';
// Het geldige emailadres van de afzender
$email_verzender = ''.$email.'';
// Een geldig emailadres of helemaal leeg laten
$bcc_emailadres = '';
// HTML mail? True/False
$html = true;

// De headers samenstellen
$headers     = 'From: ' . $website_naam . ' <' . $eigen_emailadres . '>' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'Reply-To: ' . $naam_verzender . ' <' . $email_verzender . '>' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'Return-Path: Mail-Error <' . $error_emailadres . '>' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= ($bcc_emailadres != '') ? 'Bcc: ' . $bcc_emailadres . PHP_EOL : '';
$headers    .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'X-Priority: Normal' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= ($html) ? 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL : '';
$headers    .= ($html) ? 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL : '';

mail(EMAIL_TO,MESSAGE_SUBJECT,$message_body,$headers);

}

public function setError($field, $errmsg){
$this->errors[$field]   = $errmsg;
$this->num_errors       = count($this->errors);
}

public function error_value($field){
if(array_key_exists($field,$this->errors))
return $this->errors[$field];
else
return '';
}

public function countErrors(){
return $this->num_errors;
}
};
?>    


<table width="675px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="">
<label class="label_aanhef" for="aanhef_1"><input name="aanhef" id="aanhef_1" type="radio" value="Dhr." /> Dhr.</label><label class="label_aanhef" for="aanhef_2"><input name="aanhef" id="aanhef_2" type="radio"  value="Mevr." /> Mevr.</label>
<span class="error"><?php echo $contact->error_value['aanhef']; ?></span>

<input id="contactpersoon" name="contactpersoon" maxlength="120" type="text" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error"><?php echo $contact->error_value['contactpersoon']; ?></span>
<input id="bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam" maxlength="120" type="text" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error"><?php echo $contact->error_value['bedrijfsnaam']; ?></span>
<input id="email" name="email" maxlength="120" type="text" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error"><?php echo $contact->error_value['email']; ?></span>
<input id="telefoon" name="telefoon" maxlength="120" type="text" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error"><?php echo $contact->error_value['telefoon']; ?></span>


<label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_A"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_A" value="A. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: C) < 1 Ohm" type="radio" />A) Geen eis</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_B"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_B" value="B. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: C) < 1 Ohm" type="radio"  />B) < 0,1 Ohm</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_C"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_C" value="C. Gefeliciteerd dat is het goede antwoord." type="radio"  />C) < 1 Ohm</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_D"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_D" value="D. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: C) < 1 Ohm" type="radio" />D) < 10 Ohm</label>
<span id="vraag1_antwoorden" class="foutmelding_quiz">
<?php echo $contact->error_value['vraag1_antwoorden']; ?>
</span>

<label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_A"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_A" value="A. Gefeliciteerd dat is het goede antwoord." type="radio" />A) Geen eis</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_B"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_B" value="B. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: A)  Geen eis" type="radio" />B) < 0,1 Ohm</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_C"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_C" value="C. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: A)  Geen eis" type="radio" />C) < 1 Ohm</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_D"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_D" value="D. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: A)  Geen eis" type="radio" />D) < 10 Ohm</label>
<span id="vraag2_antwoorden" class="foutmelding_quiz">
<?php echo $contact->error_value['vraag2_antwoorden']; ?>
</span>
<input class="button submit" type="submit" value="" /><input id="newcontact" name="newcontact" type="hidden" value="1"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this going to be ajaxed? WHy is there no value on the submit button?

Comment: No, used to be, but not anymore. Should the submit contain a value?

Comment: Does the button show at all? Or do you style it with CSS?

Comment: Could you have a go at formatting it with the appropriate indentations.

Comment: Could you explain your answer more please?

Comment: @Sebastian - Who was that directed to?

Comment: Towards you Ed: Could you explain me what your are trying to say?

Comment: You indent the lines between braces. It makes code easier to read. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style. It also makes it easier to spot potential errors.

Answer (score 1):

Change all of your `!isset` to `empty`.

For example:

```
if (empty($aanhef)) {
    $this->errors['aanhef'] = 'Vul uw aanhef in';
}
```

Differences:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Also, after your `header('Location: ...')` use `exit;`.

Working code here: http://pastebin.com/fZecwby1

Comment: Like this? header('Location: result.php'); exit;

Comment: The validation still does not work, header takes me to result.php without checking for empty fields..

Comment: You're not using your function setError to set your errors so your field num_errors is never updated and if($this->countErrors() == '') always returning true I guess.

Comment: So replace if($this->countErrors() == '') by if (count($this->errors)) or use your functions instead.

Comment: Its still not checking the fields with this

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php - check documentation. `exit;`, `exit();` and `exit(0);` are the same.

Comment: Did you replace all your `$this->errors[$field] = $errmsg;` by `$this->setError($field, $errmsg);` ?

Comment: Any idea where the problem might be? I changed if($this->countErrors() == '') by if (count($this->errors))

Comment: I found one record that contains $this->errors[$field] = $errmsg; thats beneath public function setError($field, $errmsg){

Thats the only one right?

Comment: Should I also change? if(empty($aanhef)) {
              $this->errors['aanhef'] = 'Vul uw aanhef in';
              }

Comment: Yes, this is not what I was telling you, sorry, it was an example, just replace all your line like `$this->errors['aanhef'] = 'Vul uw aanhef in';` by `$this->setError('aanhef', 'Vul uw aanhef in');`

Comment: Oke thanks, and should any changes be made here: public function setError($field, $errmsg){
             $this->setError($field, $errmsg);
             $this->num_errors       = count($this->errors);
            }
           
            public function error_value($field){
             if(array_key_exists($field,$this->errors))
              return $this->errors[$field];
             else
              return '';
            }
           
            public function countErrors(){
             return $this->num_errors;
            }

Comment: I;m getting a error on my page: The FastCGI Handler was unable to process the request.
Error Details:

The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
Error Number: -2147467259 (0x80004005).
Error Description: Unspecified error
HTTP Error 500 - Server Error.

Comment: Hello Smott, i'm getting this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function errors() on a non-object in C:\domains\q-international-projecten.nl\wwwroot\Denios_test\quiz.php on line 232

Comment: this is line 232: <span class="error"><?php echo $contact->errors('aanhef'); ?></span>

Comment: @smottt Can you help me with this?